# how to make python code.interact() work for a daemon

Tags: python, debugging

I have a python application running as a linux service. Sometimes it hangs(not recreatable easily) and I would like to debug with the code.interact() module.However when i issue a signal, the interactive shell does not open in my current shell, it goes to the stderr log file. How do I make it break into the current shell or is it possible to provide a shell to code.interact()

Comment: Have you considered using IPC instead?

Comment: Not sure how IPC can help ? Can you plz explain